# Exploitation With Java

Tags: exploit, java, exploit-development

I was wondering if it is possible to write exploits in java.

The Eternalblue exploit can be written in perl, ruby and even python but is it possible to write it in java?

I don't see any suitable way of doing so. Python allows you to get the target system info quite easily but is it possible with java? Java is platform independent to install but can it be used for something apart from just software development and something like exploit development?

Comment: I Googled "Eternalblue java" and got this as the first hit: https://github.com/1135/EquationExploit/blob/master/src/main/java/Exploit.java

Comment: Yeah i saw it too but it does not run the exploit independently like in python through a single script but it just passes arguements to the exe exploit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to exploit.

You can write code which exploits vulnerability in some remote system. But using plain java without any native libraries or code, you won't write exploit which needs direct access to memory.